# Using diffget in vimdiff

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I'm trying to learn to use vimdiff well. Currently I figured out how to get a block of diff from a buffer to another (using `do`) but what I'm willing to do now is to simply get one (or some) line of a block in the other buffer.

The `vimdiff` documentation says:

```
:[range]diffget
```

but I can't figure how to have a correct range parameter to simply copy the line I'm on from a buffer to the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
:.,.
```

as range from current line to the current line.

According to the doc you can omit range and then current line or line above will be used.

Comment: without range it copy the whole diff block, not just the current line.

Comment: You don’t need `,.`, just `.` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I find it a bit easier to select the current line with <kbd>V</kbd> and then to <kbd>do</kbd> or <kbd>dp</kbd>. This has the same effect as selecting the rage with <kbd>:.,.</kbd> but it is easier to type! Also, you can easily add adjacent lines with <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

As Mykola said, :.,. will specify "the current line" as the range.

I had a very large file that needed each line inspected and perhaps changed, so typing ":.,.diffput" each time was too arduous.  I recorded a macro:

```
qq:.,.diffput[ENTER]q
```

That created a macro (saved under the "q" key) to "put" a single line from the left buffer into the right buffer.  Now to repeat this action, all I have to do is type "@q"